# Start mysqld.exe but as offline at the begining

Tags: mysql, offline

How can I start my mysql server as usual using "./bin/mysqld.exe" on windows, but it has to be offline at the very begining?

Right now when I start mysqld.exe, I always need to start Mysql Workbench and push the button "bring it offline" at "instance / startup/shutdown" first. It is annoying.

I need mysql server only for localhost purposes, there is no need to be it online for the Internet.
Tried to googling and duckducking it but suprisingly there is zero talk about it.

Comment: Why?  I ask because there could be an easy workaround that involves a different solution.  Also, do you eventually make it "online" to the Internet?  Or do you confine it to multiple users on localhost?  Or just one user on localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Set `bind-address=127.0.0.1` in the `my.cnf` file to restrict all access to the localhost and local filesocket only.

Comment: I am reading that `bind-address` default value is `localhost`. Freshly installed mysql is accesible only from localhost?

Comment: @ElSajko Yes, default value `bind-address=` is equivalent to `bind-address=localhost` and that's made for security reason - server will not be exposed to the outer space w/o manual `my.cnf` modification.